# How to acess value of a dict nested inside a list of dict

Tags: python

I have a json response like this.

```
{
  "students": [
{
  "student_reference_id": "1234",
  "name": "Rajesh Pawar",
  "birth_year": "1995",
  "gender": "Male",
  "marks": [
    {
      "science": 1234,
      "physics": "2345",
    }
  ]
}
{
  "student_reference_id": "5678",
  "name": "nikita Pawar",
  "birth_year": "1996",
  "gender": "female",
  "marks": [
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to nake a list of dict like

```
  "student_reference_id": "5678",
  "name": "nikita Pawar",
  "birth_year": "1996",
  "gender": "female",
  "science": 1234,
  "physics": "2345",
```

I can do it like

```
response = response.json()
new_list = []
response = response['students']
for student in response
   for mark in student 
       temp = {
         "student_reference_id": student['student_reference_id'],
          "name": student['name'],
          "birth_year": student['birth_year'],
          "gender": student['gender'],
          "science" : mark['science'],
          "physics" : mark['physics']
    }
    new_list.append(temp)
```

Problem is, **when marks dict in response is empty** (assuming the student didn't appear for exams), above solution skips the student and that student data does nota appear in new list.

What is a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the `temp` object when iterating through `mark in student` which is why no object gets created when there aren't any marks. Try this

```
for student in response:
    temp = {
        "student_reference_id": student['student_reference_id'],
        "name": student['name'],
        "birth_year": student['birth_year'],
        "gender": student['gender']
    }
    if(len(student["marks"]) > 0):
        for mark in student["marks"][0]:
            temp[mark] = student["marks"][0][mark]

    new_list.append(temp)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.